# LinearLayout only half way clickable

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have this layout which shows title, two snippets of info about the subject (phone and address), and below all that is a linear layout which contains two buttons. Those two buttons are only clickable if I click on their top side. If I click on the bottom part, the whole window selects, if I click on the top part the button selects. I tried fixing the padding of the whole thing, but that didn't help. I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's the xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_margin="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/blue_dialog"
    style="@style/BoldStyle" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="snippet"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:maxLines = "2"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    style="@style/RegularStyle"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/telephone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="snippet"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/phone"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    style="@style/RegularStyle"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="snippet"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/contacts"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    style="@style/RegularStyle"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOffers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Offers"
        android:background="@color/blue_dialog"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        style="@style/BoldStyle"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonViewMore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View More"
        android:background="@color/blue_dialog"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        style="@style/BoldStyle"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is a basic example of what's my view. Below the red line the buttons are unclickable.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Inside nested LinearLayout you have

`android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">`

And Buttons have paddings.

Remove both marginBottom and padding - maybe this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After removing the bottom margin and the padding, I think it reacts a little bit better, but it's still not reacting as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a simple draw of what you have & want to achieve?

Additionally, you are telling your **nested layout to center it self relatively to its parent**. Try to remove

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

from the nested layout.

Additionally, remember these definitions :

1. android:gravity sets the gravity of the content of the View its used
   on.
2. android:layout_gravity sets the gravity of the View or Layout in
   its parent.

**@Edit**

Your code appears to reasonably ok regarding your objective. Try this on your nested LinearLayout that contained the button

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOffers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@color/blue_light"
        android:text="Offers"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonViewMore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:text="View More"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**@Edit 2**

Try adding

```
android:paddingBottom="30dp"
```

to the nested LinearLayout :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOffers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@color/blue_light"
            android:text="Offers"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonViewMore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:text="View More"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/UsRnAdV.png) is basically the view. Below the line the buttons are unclickable.

Comment: And the line represents the center of the LinearLayout that contains them, correct?

Comment: The line shows where the buttons become clickable. It just happens to be in the middle.

Comment: Check the edit. I have successfully implemented your layout and the buttons are triggered on every touch. Let me know of the results.

Comment: The unclickable zone is definitely smaller now, but it's still there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check my 2nd update. Add the padding and check if it gets any better.  Regards

Comment: I see what you're trying to do with that, but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. The buttons are still half clickable. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: Can you share that app's code (at least the part that concerns the buttons)? Im really curious about this case now :P

Comment: This is all I can share: http://pastebin.com/t10DUgAy I'm really out of ideas here.